# Getting HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error while running .net project

Tags: .net, iis

I have ran a command aspnet_regiis -i from command prompt and then I am getting Server Error while running the project in Visual Studio.
I have ran the command from below path:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319

IF anyone have any solution for this please let me know or if I can revert above command.

IIS version is 7.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the screenshots for the error? normally, HTTP error code 500.19 can be caused by many reasons, it is hard to detect by only saying this error.

Comment: Their is a config error saying duplicate 'System.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined in web.config
Error Code 0x800700b7

Comment: @Dhiren OK, you can see that the error message and the error code is made more sense. This a is known issue with ASP.NET Core 4.0. a workaround here is to delete or comment out all the system.web.extensions configuration section definitions and configuration section group definitions from the application-level Web.config file. These definitions are usually at the top of the application-level Web.config file and can be identified by the configSections element and its children.

Example:
Commenting out the <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions"...>

Comment: but I haven't changed anything in the code or web.config then why is it giving me error or can I run command again with -u option?

Comment: Yes, you can consider that it is an issue for ASP.NET Core 4: See http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770149

Answer (score 0):

aspnet_regiis -i means install this version of ASP.NET  that is associated with the ASP.NET IIS Registration tool, and the error message of your post indicated a problem with the version of asp.net you are using, you could try to change your .NET runtime version.

About how to correct the asp.net version you can refer to this link:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/error-occurred50019-internal-server-error-0x800700b7-there-duplicate-systemwebextensionsscriptingscriptresourcehandler-section-defined-when-launching-controller-1021-or-earlier-caused-using-net-40